# xamarin android - listView never populates

Tags: listview, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a string array that looks like this:

```
string[] uuids = new string[]{
                fashionUUID,
                foodUUID,
                electricalUUID,
                sportsUUID,
                financeUUID,
                homeGardenUUID,
                hairUUID,
                propertyUUID,
                giftsUUID,
                jewelleryUUID,
                footwareUUID
```

and a list view:

```
ListView uuidListView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.uuidList);
```

I'm then trying to display the values in a ListView upon a button click. However, my listView never gets populated with anything. Can anybody help?

```
button.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
   {
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.UUIDlist); //changes the layout

        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Resource.Id.uuidList, uuids);

   };
```

My layout file containing the listView looks like this (very simple):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:orientation="vertical"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ListView
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/uuidList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't get any errors when building, just nothing is displayed in my listView. I've also tried using a JavaList instead of a string array but as one would expect I get the same result. Am i missing something obvious when building/populating the listview?

Comment: Please post the complete source code

Comment: Done! Hopefully that's a bit clearer. sorry.

Comment: try use Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1 instead of Resource.Id.uuidList to see if it will work. post up the layout file also

Comment: @InitLipton - just tried your suggestion and no difference. Just a blank screen.

Comment: put the listview inside a layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >

Comment: First thing is that second parameter of ArrayAdapter constructor is the layout of the list item not of the list. And you also need to set the adapter for the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
button.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
     .......

     ListView uuidListView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.uuidList);
     var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Resource.Id.uuidList, uuids);
     uuidListView.Adapter = adapter; 
};
```

Comment: I have just shown how to set adapter for your list view, it might be throwing null reference exception because your "uuidListView" would be null, you have to make sure that you get the ListView object, or show me your Layout file for this activity.

Comment: why you are calling SetContentView (Resource.Layout.UUIDlist);  in your button click, your current activity has different layout?

Comment: your help is appreciated on this one. I've been stuck for ages and have become blinkered. The layout file is shown in my original post for the listView activity, i presume that's what you mean/need?

Comment: Yes i've used a different layout to display the listview. Seemed logical to me, but i'm new to android dev.

Comment: If you are not showing more detailed code, then it would be difficult to help. I don't think you can use SetContentView like this on button click.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the second parameter of `ArrayAdapter`'s constructor is **the resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when instantiating views** not the ID of the listview (`uuidList`) in the screen layout.

To make it simple, you can reuse a built-in layout for that, which is `Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1`.

So, in your button click event, it should be like this:

```
button.Click += delegate
{
    var listview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.uuidList);

    var adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,
        Android.Resource.Id.Text1, uuids);
    listview.Adapter = adapter;
};
```

`Android.Resource.Id.Text1` is an id of a bulit-in `TextView` within the `Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1`.